# Como evitar bloqueio de requisições?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, thread, iis, assincronismo

Estou fazendo um projeto em **ASP.NET MVC** + **IIS** e percebi que ao fazer uma requisição à uma página com longa leitura no Banco de Dados (utilizando ***Entity Framework***), se eu abrir outra janela e tentar acessar uma outra página qualquer do site (a Home por exemplo, que não tem nenhuma leitura e deveria abrir rapidamente), essa segunda requisição acaba esperando a primeira terminar para então exibir a página.

Estou preocupado com este tipo de bloqueio, pois quando o site estiver em produção pode acabar bloqueando a requisição de clientes e até gerando um ***timeout***.

Não sei se isso é algum tipo de configuração que deva ser inserida no IIS ou na aplicação.

Se alguem puder me ajudar com a seguinte questão, agradeço.

**PS: Não estou utilizando métodos assíncronos nas Controllers. Acredito que o método assíncrono evitaria só o congelamento da tela para o usuário, mas não interfere no bloqueio da requisições de outros clientes, mas como não tenho muito conhecimento em programação assíncrona, se eu estiver errado me corrijam.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Não sei se isso é algum tipo de configuração que deva ser inserida no IIS ou na aplicação.

Você já se respondeu neste comentário aqui:

> Não estou utilizando métodos assíncronos nas Controllers. Acredito que o método assíncrono evitaria só o congelamento da tela para o usuário, mas não interfere no bloqueio da requisições de outros clientes, mas como não tenho muito conhecimento em programação assíncrona, se eu estiver errado me corrijam.

Sim, o bloqueio ocorre porque o contexto não é preparado para *thread-safety*, então todas as operações são enfileiradas em modo síncrono.

Já em modo assíncrono, o *Controller* executa todas as instruções da *Action* que não necessitem da informação do banco, até chegar na execução de alguma interação com o contexto. Por exemplo:

```
var produtos = await db.Produtos.ToListAsync();
```

Neste caso, uma *thread* em alto nível (implementada por [`Task<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx)) será criada para fazer a execução do banco de dados. Com isso, a *Action* não bloqueia a execução de outras *Actions* concorrentes.

> Como evitar bloqueio de requisições?

Em resumo:

1. Atualizar sua solução para, no mínimo o .NET 4.5.2;
2. Usar o escopo assíncrono nas suas *Actions*:

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult> MinhaAction() { ... }
   ```
3. Ao chamar o contexto, envelopar a requisição de informação usando um método assíncrono ([`System.Data.Entity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity(v=vs.113).aspx)) e preparar o C# para desenvelopar o resultado da requisição usando `await`:

   ```
   var produtos = await db.Produtos.ToListAsync();
   ```
4. Ao usar escopo transacional, indicar ao coordenador de transação que você está usando um fluxo assíncrono:

   ```
   using System.Transactions;

   using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)) 
   {
       ...

       scope.Complete();
   }
   ```

Comment: Perfeito cara, acho que essa dúvida vai ajudar muita gente também. Agradeço pela resposta.